# Unable to pass data to MapsActivity

Tags: android

I wish to pass the input location from user (such as "hospital") to MapsActivity so that some nearby hospitals can be shown on the map. I tried to pass it as shown below but failed. Because when i show log message for the string "search", the log message cannot be displayed in logcat. Other log message can be shown but only the log message for "search" cannot be shown. So, how can I pass it?
Hope to get some help. Thanks
Below is my code.

*MainActivity*

```
 btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("search", searchWord);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

*MapsActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    //Log.e("halo:", search);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkLocationPermission();

    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    search = getIntent().getExtras().getString("search");
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //setLocation();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        bulidGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Log.e("check permission", ""+PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        Log.v("halo:", search);
    }

    setLocation();
}      

public void setLocation() {
    Object dataTransfer[] = new Object[2];
    GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
    Log.e("set location", ""+dataTransfer);


    Log.e("halo:", search);

    if (search.equalsIgnoreCase("hospital")) {
        mMap.clear();
        String hospital = "hospital";
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, hospital);
        dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
        dataTransfer[1] = url;

        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Showing Nearby Hospitals", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (search.equalsIgnoreCase("clinic")) {
        mMap.clear();
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, search);
        dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
        dataTransfer[1] = url;

        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Showing Nearby Clinics", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (search.equalsIgnoreCase("pharmacy")) {
        mMap.clear();
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, "pharmacy");
        dataTransfer[0] = mMap;
        dataTransfer[1] = url;

        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Showing Nearby Pharmacy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(search.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


private String getUrl(double latitude , double longitude , String nearbyPlace)
{

    StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("location="+latitude+","+longitude);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius="+PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&type="+nearbyPlace);
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"AIzaSyBLEPBRfw7sMb73Mr88L91Jqh3tuE4mKsE");

    Log.d("MapsActivity", "url = "+googlePlaceUrl.toString());

    return googlePlaceUrl.toString();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(100);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MapsActivity have you tried moving this line:

```
search = getIntent().getExtras().getString("search");
```

above the onCreate method, just after:

```
public class StationsMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

I think this would make accessible to all other methods in the class rather than only the onCreate method where you've placed it.